# Polymer 0.8: data-binding in the <content> select property not working

Tags: javascript, polymer

In polymer 0.5, i could use directly a property in the  select attribute and the nodes were correctly filtered.

In polymer 0.8, if i try to used data-binding it will not work.

```
<dom-module id="test-element">
    <template>
        <content id="p0" select="[selected-item]"></content>
        <span>{{selector}}</span>
        <content id="p1" select="{{selector}}"></content>
    </template>
</dom-module>
<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'test-element',
        properties: {
            selector: {
                type: 'String',
                value: '[selected-item]'
            }
        },
        ready: function() {
            console.log(
                //show: 3
                Polymer.dom(this.$.p0).getDistributedNodes().length,
                //show: 6
                Polymer.dom(this.$.p1).getDistributedNodes().length
            );
        }
    });
</script>

<test-element>
    <div selected-item>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div selected-item>3</div>
    <div selected-item>4</div>
</test-element>
```

Is it a bad idea ? Did someones succeed with that ?

Comment: The [migration guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.8/docs/migration.html#data-binding) sais in 0.8 data binding is one-way by default. I haven't used 0.8 yet, but be sure to take a look at it.

Comment: I verify. The doc specifies that a two data-binding must use {{}} and notify:true in the definition. But in fact it does not change my problem. By the way if you try to display that element you'll see that the {{selector}} is correctly displayed in the <span> which means that it's displayed in the localDOM but does not impact the filtering.